# Can I change the router's interface ip?

Tags: openstack

Can I change the router's interface ip to a new one?

[image]

No matter in the dashboard or terminal, if we can change the ip?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

1: `neutron router-list`

note down the id of router of whose you want to change interface IP address.

2: `ip netns`

to see the namespace of router. It would be **qrouter-{idOfRouter}**

3: `ip netns exec qrouter-{idOfRouter} ifconfig`

to check if the selected namespace if of the desired router or not.

4: `ip netns exec qrouter-{idOfRouter} ifconfig <port-name> <newIPOfSameClass>`

to change the ip address of the interface

5: `ip netns exec qrouter-{idOfRouter} ifconfig <port-name>`

to check if interface ip has changed or not.

This might help.